# How to animate row child while being removed from widget tree?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, animation

Consider this widget

```dart
Widget buildUI(){
  return Row(
    children: [
      if(condition)
        Widget1(),
      Widget2(),
    ],
  );
}
```

when `condition` becomes false, `Widget1` is removed from the tree and from the screen as well, but it does so without any exit animation.
what I want is to have animation, where, when `Widget2` takes all the space left behind `Widget1`, and also when `Widget1` leaves the screen, I want these 2 events (that happen when `condition` becomes false) to be animated (maybe fade effect for removal of `Widget1`, and translation and scale effect for movement of `Widget2` to its new position.

How can I achieve this?

I tried wrapping the widgets with `FooTransition` widgets but it didn't work, no animation.

Note: I prefer solutions without using external packages, but if its too verbose to implement it then no problem